# POST to PHP from different HTML files using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 3 HTML file that I am using to upload the pictures to a specific folder and sub folder. The problem that I am facing is when I POST from 1st and 2nd HTML page I can move the image to the specific folder and sub-folder but as soon as I POST the FILE from the 3rd HTML, it gives me a success alert but the image is not uploaded. Below are the codes.

PHP:

```
 if(isset($_POST))
{
    session_start();
    //The target location for the image to be stored.
    $_SESSION['str'];
    $_SESSION['str1'];
    $_SESSION['str2'];
    //To rename the file
    $_SESSION['img'];
    $_SESSION['img1'];
    $_SESSION['img2'];

     //1st IF statement
     if(!empty($_FILES["info_file"]["name"])){

     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['info_file']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str'].$_SESSION['img']);


    }
    else 
        {
        //2nd IF statement
        if(!empty($_FILES["info_file1"]["name"])){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['info_file1']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str1'].$_SESSION['img1']);
        }
        else
        {
            if(!empty($_FILES["info_file2"]["name"]))
            {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['info_file2']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str2'].$_SESSION['img2']);
            }
        }
        }
}
```

HTMLs:

1st.

```
<script>

function readURL(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(300)
                .height(340);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
   uploadfunc();

  }
</script>
<script> 
function uploadfunc(){  
     if(!navigator.onLine){ 
        alert("你已離線，請再試一次");
        return false;   
    }else{
     var formData = new FormData();
     var info_file_data = $('#imageid').prop('files')[0];
     console.log(info_file_data);
      formData.append('info_file', info_file_data);
      // for 2nd and 3rd HTML onlt this 'info_file' changed to 'info_file1' and 'info_file2' respectively.
     $.ajax({
          url: 'login.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
          dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          data: formData,                         
          type: 'post',
          success: function(php_script_response){
            alert ("上載成功/ Upload Successful");
          }
        });
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body style="text-align:center">


<h1 style="color:#F00">SMArt-InterAct</h1><br/>

<h2 style="color:#03F">相片上載</h2>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" method="POST">
     <input type="file" required id="imageid" name="image" onChange="readURL(this);" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="你的相片" /><br/><br/>
     <input type="button" class="test" value="上傳"/>
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi,what is u r need can u explain clearly ?

Comment: Your success alert is shown because you use IF statement to check `$_FILES["info_file"]["name"]`. You should use `if (move_uploaded_file(...)) { echo 'Upload Successful'; }` instead.

Comment: @KarthikKeyan The problem that I am facing is, When I POST file from 1st HTML, the image is stored to the desired location using first "if" statement. When i POST using the 2nd HTML, it goes into the "else" part and the image is uploaded. But when i POST from the 3rd HTML it doesnt go in to the "else" part of the 2nd "if" statement. See the code above to get the numbering of the "if".

Comment: @Nikko Please check HTML code. The Upload Successful comes from the AJAX as a alert.

Comment: @Vishu you didn't check anything before sending alert, even a syntax error in PHP will trigger the alert. Can you add `console.log(php_script_response);` and see the PHP response on browser's console?

Comment: In the <script> I have checked the PHP_SCRIPT_RESPONSE. Please have a look at the block $.ajax. ANd in the browser console it doesnt provide any error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself for this question. Just posting the if-else part and not the whole code.

```
 //1st IF statement
           if(!empty($_FILES["info_file"]["name"]))
      {
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES['info_file']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str'].$_SESSION['img']);
         echo "$asd";
     }
         if (!empty($_FILES["info_file1"]["name"])){
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['info_file1']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str1'].$_SESSION['img1']);
            echo "$asd1";
            }

      if(empty($_FILES["info_file"]["name"]) || empty($_FILES["info_file1"]["name"]) ){

   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['info_file2']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str2'].$_SESSION['img2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing mistake in if else pls try this code

```
 if(isset($_POST))
    {
        session_start();
        //The target location for the image to be stored.
        $_SESSION['str'];
        $_SESSION['str1'];
        $_SESSION['str2'];
        //To rename the file
        $_SESSION['img'];
        $_SESSION['img1'];
        $_SESSION['img2'];

         //1st IF statement
         if(!empty($_FILES["info_file"]["name"])){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['info_file']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str'].$_SESSION['img']);
             echo 'Upload Successful';
        }
        else if(!empty($_FILES["info_file1"]["name"])){
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['info_file1']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str1'].$_SESSION['img1']);
            }else{
               move_uploaded_file($_FILES['info_file2']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str2'].$_SESSION['img2']);
                }     
    }
```

Comment: Can you debug $_FILES when you are trying to upload from third file. My guess is that variable name might be not correct for third file.
Debug code : echo '<pre>';print_r($_FILES);die;

Comment: @joyd Sorry I didnt get you. Can you please add Debug Code in the code above and Post it back please.

Comment: `code`
 if(isset($_POST))
{
    session_start();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_FILES);
    die('here') 
    ..............
`code`

Comment: @joyd No. there is nothing in the console of the browser even. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: what was the output from print_r($_FILES)  when you tried to upload via third file ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80564/discussion-between-joy-d-and-vishu).